# Как избежать размытия SVG-фигуры?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как избежать размытия svg-фигуры при процентном `margin`? Вот код:

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    <svg width="9" height="20">
        <path fill="#000000" d="M4,1h1v17H4V1z" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  margin-left: 9%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evyf0b3e/

Процентная установка `margin` нужна для правильного функционирования сайта.

Comment: А что за размытие? У меня все норм

Comment: @korytoff скорее всего имеется в виду рендеринг svg в файрфоксе. В вебкитах всё будет ок

Comment: Да, в других браузерах не проверял, именно в Firefox. Это из-за дробного смещения основного блока, когда `margin-left: 9%' попадает, например, на 397.5px. Пока лечу округленим смещения в JS, но если есть решение получше, буду рад о нем узнать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел другое решение - отключить сглаживание фигуры свойством `shape-rendering`. Код будет выглядеть так:

```
<div class = "a">
    <svg width="9" height="20">
        <path fill="#000000" shape-rendering="crispEdges" d="M4,1h1v17H4V1z" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evyf0b3e/2/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
<div class = "a">
  <svg width="5" height="17" viewBox="0 0 5 17">
    <path fill="#000000" d="M4,1h1v17H4V1z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d5an2hmL/

Comment: Как я понял, разница только в `viewBox="0 0 5 17"` и измененных размерах? Это "решает" проблему только в частном случае, и, все же, на четных значениях `margin-left`изображение немного размывается. Сам по себе `viewBox` проблему нецелочисленных координат не решит.

Comment: Разница в размерах области просмотра. Если ограничить область строго размерами фигуры, то размытия по краям можно максимально убрать для фигур, контур которых совпадает с границами просмотра: https://jsfiddle.net/d5an2hmL/1/